# Java Synchronized concept in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

### Condition

I have comma separated list of airway bill numbers in a record in table core_config_data. This table uses engine Innodb.

I have a class with a function to take read this record, explode it, unshift one airway bill number, implode rest and save in database again.

### Problem

When 2 or more people press assign airway bill number at same instance, all the shipment get same airway bill numbers.

### Question

Is there a way in php / magento / zend to implement synchronized for this kind of situation.

Regards,
Saurabh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use locks, but I suggest to create a table for airway bill numbers.

```
SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Will it work if I have master slave environment. I use Master to insert and slaves to read.

Comment: I couldn't find a clear documentation about this specific problem, but I think it's logical to update the slave since you are reading from it.

Comment: If you grab the numbers from the master, you'll be clear for those saves.

Answer (score 0):

- You could use redis for this with blpop/push.(performs best I guess)
- You could use
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock
- You should also read about
  transactions =>
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction